# my ajax action doesn't get hit

Tags: ajax

I have this action in my plugin page.

```
add_action ( 'init', 'myStartSession', 1 );
function join_action() {
    $a = 1;
    include "includes/join.php";
}
add_action ( 'admin_post_nopriv_join', 'join_action' );
add_action ( 'admin_post_join', 'join_action' );
```

and I call this from my angularjs app as follows:

```
$scope.join = function() {
        $scope.formData.action = "join";
        $http(
        {
            method : 'POST',
            url : '<?php echo MEMBERSHIP_APP; ?>',
            data : jQuery.param($scope.formData), // pass in data as strings
            headers : {
                'Content-Type' : 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
            }
        })
        .success(
            function(data) {
                console.log(data);
                if (!data.success) {
                    // if not successful, bind errors to error variables

                } else {
                    // if successful, bind success message to message
                    $scope.message = data.message;
                }
            });
        };
```

where MEMBERSHIP_APP points to wp-admin/admin-ajax.php

Please can you see what I am doing wrong. I have used this construct many times before.

Comment: did you check inside network tab in developer tools? what it is returns?

Answer (score 0):

Okay I see my error I used `admin_post` instead of `wp_ajax` so here is how it should have been:

```
add_action ( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_join', 'join_action' );
add_action ( 'wp_ajax_join', 'join_action' );
```

Answer (score 0):

add _action after your action name in javascript code . like :

```
$scope.formData.action = "join_action";
```

and rename function , remove action from that like :

```
function join() {
    $a = 1;
    include "includes/join.php";
}
```

if you want working example , here it it :

```
add_action('wp_ajax_your_function_name_action','your_function_name_ajax')
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_your_function_name_action','your_function_name_ajax')

if (!function_exists('somename')) {
function somename(){
echo $_POST['eidvar'];
exit();
}
}



var data = {
action: 'your_function_name_action',
eidvar: "somevalue",
}

$.post(MEMBERSHIP_APP, data).done(function(response) {
if(response.indexOf("no") > -1) {
//no result etc
} else {
console.log(response)}
});
```